# Cascade onDelete is not deleting join data using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

SequelizeJS onDelete Cascade is not deleting join table records, below is my code

```
company.hasMany(employee, {foreignKey: 'companyId'});

employee.belongsTo(company, {foreignKey: 'companyId', onUpdate: 'CASCADE', onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
```

here company is parent and employee is child

```
company.hasMany(vendor, {foreignKey: 'companyId'});

vendor.belongsTo(company, {foreignKey: 'companyId', onUpdate: 'CASCADE', onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
```

here company is parent and vendor is child

my delete route code:

```
router.delete('/company/:companyId', function(req, res){
        var companyId = req.params.companyId;
        dataSet.destroy({where: {companyId: companyId}}, include: [employee, vendor])
            .then(function(response){
                res.json(response);
            })
        .catch(function(err){
            res.json(err)
        })
});
```

here while deleting, company getting deleted but employee and child not deleting.

Update:

this query is executing while calling company.destroy();

```
DELETE FROM company WHERE companyId = 2;
```

is there any other way to perform delete method ? is my code ryt?

Comment: What is the `companyId` field definition in migration file responsible for creating the `employee` or `vendor` database tables? And after you perform the delete, what value is in `companyId` column in those two tables?

Comment: 1. company_id, eg: if am deleting companyId = 2, this 2 is the companyId of both employee and vendor